# SwiftUI VStack align right single element

Tags: ios, swiftui, alignment, vstack

I'm new at SwiftUI, I'm trying this time to align right a single element (an image) to the right and then the rest of the content should be center aligned.

Just like what happens when you use `Spacer()` on an `HStack` but to the other side.

I read about `.alignmentGuide` and it was a little bit confusing but I tried using it this way:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Hello!").alignmentGuide(.trailing) {
                    v in v[HorizontalAlignment.trailing]
                }
            }
            Text("Hello, World!")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

But this makes no change at all, both `Text` are center aligned.

I tried moving the `.alignmentGuide` code after the `}` of the `HStack` with the same result.

This is what I'm trying to do, before with storyboards I'd use some constraints to do this, like setting the right constraint to 8 or something, but I'm a bit lost when it comes to doing it the SwiftUI way.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Hello!")
                    .padding(.trailing, 8)
            }
            Text("Hello, World!")
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

Use an `HStack` with a `Spacer()` to push `Text("Hello!")` to the right.  Add `.padding(.trailing, 8)` to keep it 8 points off the right edge.

Comment: Is this really the recommended way to do that? Sounds very verbose for something so basic as `align-self: flex-end`.

Comment: You're right, I don't think it's recommended. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72944281/10967642) for more explanation.

Answer (score 11):

To answer to @cheesus, I would say @vacawama's answer is not the recommended way of doing it.

### Here is how I would do it

```swift
VStack {
  Text("Hello!")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
    .padding(.trailing, 8)
  Text("Hello, World!")
}
.frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
```

### To elaborate a bit more

The main problem with using `(H|V)Stack`s and `Spacer`s is that you get a fixed spacing between your content and the `Spacer`, and in some cases it might cause issues.

#### An example

- Consider we want a `HStack`, some spacing between elements and the last text aligned to the left:

  ```swift
  HStack(spacing: 25) {
    Color.red
      .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
    Color.green
      .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
    Text("The text")
      .background(Color.blue)
    Spacer()
  }
  .frame(width: 250)
  .border(Color.yellow)
  .padding(8)
  ```

  It gives:
  [image: Example 1]
- If the text becomes longer, you see the `HStack` spacing between the spacer:

  ```
  - Text("The text")
  + Text("Some long text")
  ```

  [image: Example 2]
- Now I just replaced the `Spacer` with a `Color` so you can see it in action:

  ```
  - Text("Some long text")
  -   .background(Color.blue)
  - Spacer()
  + Text("Some long text")
  +   .background(Color.blue)
  +   .layoutPriority(1)
  + Color.indigo
  +   .frame(height: 20)
  +   .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  ```

  [image: Example 3]
- This is fixed if you use `.frame(alignment:)`:

  ```swift
  HStack(spacing: 25) {
    Color.red
      .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
    Color.green
      .frame(width: 50, height: 20)
    Text("Some long text")
      .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
      .background(Color.blue)
  }
  .frame(width: 250)
  .border(Color.yellow)
  .padding(8)
  ```

  [image: Example 4]

Comment: This seems to be better than the accepted answer